# How to remove selected windows10 updates?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update, windows-10-v1703

in Windows 10,

1) How can you know/search if a specific update package is installed on your system (i am talking about these update files named like KB123456...)?

2) And if one is possible, how can you select and completely de-install/remove a specific update package?

3) Can you even do that in the process of a Clean Install (when using Microsoft's official ISO file), removing your desired updates from the ISO installer file, so that you are installing it directly without them?

4) Is there any update package that you may know of which has "bugs" and should be avoided to install?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can you know/search if a specific update package is installed on your system (i am talking about these update files named like KB123456...)?

Any update installed for specific version of Windows 10 will appear in the Windows Update history.  Once a feature update is installed, updates for the previous version are no longer applicable, so the update history is wiped.

> And if one is possible, how can you select and completely de-install/remove a specific update package?

Some updates become require for numerous reasons and cannot be installed.  If an update can be uninstalled the option to uninstall that update will be offered from within Windows Update and Add/Remove Programs.

> Can you even do that in the process of a Clean Install (when using Microsoft's official ISO file), removing your desired updates from the ISO installer file, so that you are installing it directly without them?

Performing an update on the installation files is an optional step.  However, it is not recommended to skip any update, you should keep your system updated whenever possible.  It is not enough to be running the current cumulative update to a specific version of Windows 10, you need to make sure, you are running a supported version of Windows 10.  You will typically be warned if you are using a version of Windows 10 that is no longer supported.

> Is there any update package that you may know of which has "bugs" and should be avoided to install?

Microsoft documents all verified issue for all versions of Windows 10 [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-information/)

Answer (score 1):

For 1. Open Start, Settings, Update and then View Update History. This will show you what has been installed.  Start, Settings, About will show you what version you have installed.

For 2. Get wushowhide.diagcab from Microsoft Downloads and use that to hide specific updates.  I have not needed this in some years (Printer updates were an issue 3 or 4 years ago but not recently)

For 3.  No not really. A clean install will install everything. You need to uninstall and hide updates you do not want.

For 4. I do not know of any updates that should be avoided. We try to keep all client machines current and up to date and there is nothing right now that should be avoided. Microsoft has cleared up most issues and is lengthening the time between feature upgrades. Version 1909 is now in fairly wide adoption and it came out less than 90 days ag.